# Improve a performance of a query that filters on foreign table's column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm about to improve a performance of a query that joins a large table to other table providing:

- There exists an index on a foreign key leading to other table.
- The query filters the data using "the other table's" column.
- one hint - Entity framework is joining the tables.
- The main table has around 20 million records

For example:

- There exists one large table ItemsTable.
- The ItemsTable joins to other table "TypesTable" using column typeId.
- There exists nonclustered index on typeId column of ItemsTable.

```
SELECT * 
FROM
    ItemsTable l
    JOIN TypesTable t ON l.typeId = t.id
WHERE 
    statusId <> 1 
    AND t.SomeFlag = 1
```

Despite there exists an index on a foreign key (typeId in the example), the query performs badly,

The execution plan: https://www.pastiebin.com/59f33fed82bc0

I've noticed that creating view that flattens the schema (that is joins to types table and "someFlag" is being returned in a row) the performance problem disappears.

I'm about to create a view that does the join. Is there other a way to improve the performance of such a query?

---

I've noticed that the problem can be resolved by adding order by clause to the query. In the above query adding the "order by typeId" makes the sql server use the index created on type column.

Comment: You have top 10 but no order by. Without an order by you have now way of knowing which rows are going to be returned.

Comment: It was an example, I'll remove top 10 because it's not a part of the problem

Comment: Please post the EXPLAIN and the schema.

Comment: Here you are https://www.pastiebin.com/59f33fed82bc0

Comment: It turns out that the order by typeId solves the problem and the index is being used properly:D

Answer (score 1):

For this query:

```
SELECT TOP 10 *
FROM ItemsTable l JOIN
     TypesTable t
     ON l.typeId = t.id
WHERE statusId <> 1 AND t.SomeFlag = 1;
```

The best indexes are likely to be `TypesTable(someFlag, id)` and `ItemsTable(typeid, statusId)`.

Your query would have poor performance if most items have a status of 1.

Comment: SELECT TOP 10 *
FROM ItemsTable l JOIN
     TypesTable t
     ON l.typeId = t.id
WHERE statusId <> 1 AND typeId = 1

works fine

Comment: Only adding t.SomeFlag=1 breaks the index usage